# Mutt deletes Gmail's Sent mail?

Tags: mutt

Today, I set up a couple of Gmail accounts in mutt. I'm using offlineimap to do the syncing. I used [this](http://thomas.pelletier.im/2010/10/low-memory-mail-client/) post as a guide. After the initial sync which took several hours, I logged into the web interface and found the *Sent mail* folder empty.

Is this normal? Is there a way I can set up mutt not to do that?

**Edit:**

```
[general]
ui = ttyui
accounts = Gmail, ...
pythonfile=~/.mutt/offlineimap.py

[Account Gmail]
localrepository = Gmail-Local
remoterepository = Gmail-Remote

Repository Gmail-Local]
type = Maildir
localfolders = ~/Mail/Gmail

[Repository Gmail-Remote]
type = Gmail
remoteuser = ...@gmail.com
remotepasseval = get_keychain_pass(account='...@gmail.com')
realdelete = no
nametrans = lambda folder: re.sub('.*Spam$', 'spam', re.sub('.*Drafts$', 'drafts',  re.sub('.*Sent Mail$', 'sent', re.sub('.*Starred$', 'flagged', re.sub('.*Trash$', 'trash', re.sub('.*All Mail$', 'archive', folder))))))
```

Comment: offlineimap should not delete sent mail by default.  perhaps it would help if you posted the relevant parts of your `.offlineimaprc`

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified `folderfilter` in `.offlineimaprc`?

If so, include '[Gmail]/Sent Mail':

```
folderfilter = lambda foldername: foldername in [
  # other folders you want synced ...

  #'Sent Mail',
  '[Gmail]/Sent Mail',
  ]
```